# Most efficient way of storing database information in memory using C#

Tags: c#, caching, memory-management, architecture

I am currently busy experimenting with things in C#, so that I can build a web server to my liking. The web server will be specially made for a project that I'm also working on. In the hope it will run better than other web servers.

Now what I've been trying to do is to find a efficient way to store database information in the memory of the application.

So far I've tried making a class that resembles a table with it's fields. Creating a new instance of that class for every row in a table. Then create certain Dictionary variables that resembles the indexes. Like one for Id, one for Username. It's working, but it consumes about 3x the memory compare to the table in the database. Example of what I've done:

```
class User()
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    //other columns, the same way
}
```

As for the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, User> UserIDIndex = new Dictionary<int, User>();
User NewUser = new User();
NewUser.Name = "Something...";
UserIDIndex.Add(someId, NewUser);
```

I've also tried DataTable, but wasn't a success at all. It consumed at least 50% more memory than the class and dictionaries method.

I am curious if there's any other way, a more efficient way of storing information?

Reason behind all this: A lot of data needs to be updated and selected every second. I'm afraid it's too much to do it directly from the database. So at first (start up & certain conditions) wanna load some things in the memory. Then, at some points, update the values inside the memory. Then once so many seconds, update these values in the database. This could've been done with NodeJS as well I suppose, but it's using 1 core, and I find that a little sad. Not really future proof if you run into CPU problems.

Comment: I am building a real-time application, the more users are online, the more connections / queries has to be done. With 2-4 actions per second per user, it can go way beyond the 200. And in a case like this I do believe some caching is needed. I will check out the software you suggested.

Comment: Compared with stackoverflow's database access, I don't think that in-database query cannot handle such volume of request. Even after being deadlocked, it is good after some fixing http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/

Comment: what's the expected volume?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an observable collection like is used behind the scenes in Entity Framework Core (EF Core). (I have not looked under the hood, I have observed that the .local provides me access to the in-memory copy)

```
Public ObservableCollection<user> users = new ObservableCollection<user>();
```

Since using EF Core use this same structure under the hood, you can write things that allow you easily go back and forth between using them. The tricky part is defining things in such a way that it is really easy to use either EF Core, or your InMemory implementation. The following sample is based on using EF Core. In the code below I create a common base to work from. I wrap the DbContext used by Ef Core. The wrapper allows me to access the local in memory data that resides in entity framework.

Now that the data is in memory, you just have to save it to disk. Since you have EF Core as an option, it would be easy to compare options with and without for your environment. For quick tests, I serialized to file. It was easy to reload from the same file to get back to my saved state as well.

WARNING: my wrapper just loads the entire database into memory because it is small in my case. .ToList() is the code that makes sure the data is loaded to memory in EF Core.

Check out this link for [Entity Framework Core How To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite)

CODE:

```
using Blog.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Blog
{
    public interface IData_Common
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; }
        ObservableCollection<Other> Others { get; }
    }

    public interface IData_InMemoryContext : IData_Common
    {
        IData_InMemoryContext Create();
    }

    public class Data_InMemoryContext : IData_InMemoryContext
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Other> Others { get; set; }

        public Data_InMemoryContext()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            Others = new ObservableCollection<Other>();
        }

        public IData_InMemoryContext Create()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            Others = new ObservableCollection<Other>();

            return new Data_InMemoryContext();
        }

    }

    public interface IData_Context
    {
        DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        DbSet<Other> Others { get; set; }

        IData_Context Create();
    }

    public class Data_Context : DbContext, IData_Context
    {
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Other> Others { get; set; }

        public IData_Context Create()
        {
            return new Data_Context();
        }

        public Data_Context()
        {
            //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    // I wrap context so that I can use the InMemoryContext interface
    public class WrapData_Context : IData_InMemoryContext
    {
        private object _Context;
        private DbSet<User> _Users;
        private DbSet<Other> _Others;

        public WrapData_Context(Data_Context DbContext)
        {
            if (DbContext is null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("DbContext can't be null");
            }
            _Context = DbContext;
            // Need to make sure the data is accessed so it is loaded to the local ObservableCollections
            DbContext.Users.ToList();
            _Users = DbContext.Users;
            DbContext.Others.ToList();
            _Others = DbContext.Others;
        }

        public IData_InMemoryContext Create()
        {
            var context = new Data_Context();
            return new WrapData_Context(context);
        }

        // Properties
            public ObservableCollection<User> Users => _Users.Local.ToObservableCollection();
            public ObservableCollection<Other> Others => _Others.Local.ToObservableCollection();

    }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
Data_Context _c = new Data_Context();
WrapData_Context _context = new WrapData_Context(_c);
```

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view, your approach may be good, if the performance of grouped SQL request is significantly better than a sequence of individual requests.

The main inconvenient concerns the robustness of your application in case of crash. Implement some recovery mechanism may be required.

Concerning the memory, it's difficult to evaluate the memory requirements by observing the available RAM, because the memory is not freed immediatly : its done at system's demand when needed.

To compute the really used memory, evaluate the size of your objects and multiply by the count.

*When processing a user input, did you evaluate the average computation time
with **and** without the database update ?*

Comment: Not for the real-time features. I didn't get to that part yet as I have been searching for a way that I feel it's going to work. From some tests that I've ran, I noticed that there's quite a strict limitation on the amount of connections per second on the MySQL database, even after changing the settings. Around 250/s, that's where it goes wrong in about 1.5 minute of running. The process just crashes then. And that kinda gave me the idea to find another way...

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with the way I store information, then I guess... I would be using about 4GB of RAM. 0.6-1GB for static information, 3GB for online users, if of course I get a ton of them online at the same time. Time will tell if that's going to happen. As for the recovery mechanism, well I was thinking of updating the updated information once in a while to the database. Like making sure the information in the memory, and the information in the database is never going to be 30 seconds out of sync. Perhaps real-time logging for important cases. So in case of a crash I can recover.

Comment: Did you envisage to push the update requests in a memory list and to pop all list  on a secondary thread sleeping x seconds between the pop actions?

Comment: In fact I was thinking of something like that yes. Probably one of my next goals / things-to-do in fact. I've learned a bit here and there about threading and tasks already, but not really applied it yet... so not sure what problems I'll face when I start using it.